# How can I use onAddCallBack to make the newest added items to a ReorderableList to be default?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private Vector2 scrollPos;
    private SerializedProperty conversations;
    private ConversationTrigger conversationTrigger;
    private ReorderableList conversationList;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");
        conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)target;        

        conversationList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, conversations)
        {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,

            onAddCallback = addcallback =>
            {
                addcallback.list[addcallback.list.Count] = default;
            },

            drawElementCallback = (rect, index, isActive, isSelected) =>
            {
                var element = conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

                var name = element.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                // do this for all properties

                var position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(rect, new GUIContent(name.stringValue));

                EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, name);
            },

            elementHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // Load the current values from the real component into the serialized copy
        serializedObject.Update();

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Conversations", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        var newSize = EditorGUILayout.IntField(conversations.arraySize);
        conversations.arraySize = Mathf.Max(0, newSize);

        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(250));

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        conversationList.DoLayoutList();

        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add new conversation"))
        {
            conversations.arraySize++;
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (conversations.arraySize != 0)
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Remove conversation"))
            {
                if (conversations.arraySize > 0) conversations.arraySize--;
            }
        }

        GUILayout.Space(100);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            conversationTrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(conversationTrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            conversationTrigger.LoadConversations();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

There are two main problems :

First : The properties displayAdd and displayRemove must be true in order to be able to use the onAddCallback. Maybe only displayAdd must be true. If it's false I used a break point and it's never get to the line :

```
addcallback.list[addcallback.list.Count] = default;
```

If both true it's getting to this line but the idea is to set the newest added items to the ReorderableList to be default empty without a name since now when adding a new Conversation it's duplicating the last item. Instead I want to add a new empty item.

Second : This line is just not working even if it's getting there it's just does nothing it keep adding duplicated items :

```
addcallback.list[addcallback.list.Count] = default;
```

How can I use the onAddCallback when both displayAdd  and displayRemove are false ? I want them to be false since I'm faking add/remove using two buttons.
But if they false I can't use the onAddCallback

And how to set and make that when adding a new item it will be empty without a name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you override `onAddCallback` you have to actively increase the `arraySize` which is the default behaviour if you don't override it.

```
                // you don't have to go through the list property
                // you could ofcourse but anyway you already know which list
                // you want to change
onAddCallback = list =>
{
    // first add one element
    conversations.arraySize++;
    // then get that element
    var newIndex = conversations.arraySize - 1;
    var newElement = conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(newIndex);

    // now reset all properties like
    var name = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
    name.stringValue = "";

    // ...
},
```

Note that this won't work together with your

```
GUILayout.Button("Add new conversation")
```

nor adding new elements via the

```
EditorGUILayout.IntField(conversations.arraySize);
```

---

For the first you can simply do the same like

```
if(GUILayout.Button("Add new conversation"))
{
    // first add one element
    conversations.arraySize++;
    // then get that element
    var newIndex = conversations.arraySize - 1;
    var newElement = conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(newIndex);

    // now reset all properties like
    var name = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
    name.stringValue = "";
}
```

For the second you would have to check if you removed elements or added and howmany:

```
EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
{
    var newSize = EditorGUILayout.IntField(conversations.arraySize);
}
if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
{
    if(newSize > conversations.arraySize)
    {
        // elements have to be added -> how many?
        var toAdd = newSize - conversations.arraySize - 1;
        // why -1 ? -> We add the first element and set its values to default
        // now if we simply increase the arraySize for the rest of the elements
        // they will be all a copy of the first -> all defaults ;)

        // first add one element
        conversations.arraySize++;
        // then get that element
        var newIndex = conversations.arraySize - 1;
        var newElement = conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(newIndex);

        // now reset all properties like
        var name = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
        name.stringValue = "";

        // now for the rest simply increase arraySize
        conversations.arraySize += toAdd;
    }
    else
    {
        // for removing just make sure the arraySize is not under 0
        conversations.arraySize = Mathf.Max(newSize, 0);
    }
}
```

---

Unfortunately that's the thing with Unity EditorScripting .. until now it kind of sucks and gets very complex just to get the layout you want ;)

But they are working on it and the new alpha and beta versions 2019.2 and 2019.3 already give some previews of the new Inspector and Unity GUI and there might be a simplier way to do Editor designs soon ... ;)

Comment: I'm getting exception on the line : conversations.arraySize += toAdd; Array size must be non-negative. This happen when I'm typing in the Conversations int field a value. If I click the button Add new conversation it's working fine but when changing ro adding new value in the Conversations int field it's showing the exception.

Comment: Oh my bad .. ofcourse has to be `var toAdd = newSize - conversations.arraySize - 1` otherwise you get a negative number